# Counting number of ratings without a loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, group-by

In python, given a list of ratings as:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'ratings_ml100k.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(path,sep= ',')
print(data)    
         user_id  item_id  rating
28422      100      690       4  
32020      441      751       4  
15819      145      265       5
```

where the items are:

```
print(itemsTrain)
[ 690  751  265 ..., 1650 1447 1507]
```

**For each item**, I would like to compute **the number of ratings**. Is there anyway to do this without resorting to a **Loop**? All ideas are appreciated,

`data` is a pandas dataframe. The desire output should look like this:

```
 pop = 
 item_id   rating_count
 690          120
 751          10
 265          159
  ...         ...
```

Note that `itemsTrain` contain unique item_ids in the rating dataset `data`.

Comment: What type is `data`?

Comment: python does not have a type "dataframe", do you mean [pandas.DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant pandas.DataFrame as you mentioned.

Comment: you can try [pandas.DataFrame.count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), though I am not sure about the relation to `itemsTrain`...

Comment: any implementation will use a `loop` concept behind the scenes - it is not possible to do something for every item of an array without iteration / recursion - what exactly do you mean "without resorting to a Loop"?

Comment: Can you suggest the loop version please? an example I mean

Comment: @yasyasi, can you post your expected / desired output?

Comment: This and much more are in the quickstart [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), give it a read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [200]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,8,(15,2)),columns=['id', 'rating'])

In [201]: df
Out[201]:
    id  rating
0    4       6
1    0       1
2    2       4
3    2       5
4    2       7
5    3       5
6    6       1
7    4       3
8    4       3
9    3       2
10   2       4
11   7       7
12   3       1
13   2       7
14   7       3

In [202]: df.groupby('id').rating.count()
Out[202]:
id
0    1
2    5
3    3
4    3
6    1
7    2
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

if you want to have result as a DF (you can also name the `count` column as you wish):

```
In [206]: df.groupby('id').rating.count().to_frame('count').reset_index()
Out[206]:
   id  count
0   0      1
1   2      5
2   3      3
3   4      3
4   6      1
5   7      2
```

you can also count # of unique ratings:

```
In [203]: df.groupby('id').rating.nunique()
Out[203]:
id
0    1
2    3
3    3
4    2
6    1
7    2
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Excellent. This is what I meant by without loop. However, why do you group by `id` and what does unique ratings mean in this case? we have a number of users who have rated a number of items with specific ratings. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `df.groupby()` to group items by `item_id` and then use the method `count()` to sum the ratings.

Do as follows :

```
# df is your dataframe
                               v # the method allows you to sum values of the previous feature
df.groupby('item_id').rating.count()
      ^                 ^ # the feature you want to sum upon its values
      ^
   # The method allows you to group the samples by the feature "item_id"
   # which is supposed to be unique
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same logic as the existing answer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : Yes it's the same. Sorry I was writing the answer when it was already posted.

Comment: Thanks. I want to rename the new column. I tried `cnt = data.groupby('item_id').rating.count()
cnt.columns = ['item_id','count']`, but the second column still doesn't have any label. How can I fix this too?

Comment: @yasyasi, `data.groupby('item_id').rating.count().to_frame('count').reset_index()`